# Why can't rspec find _path method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

The app's routes.rb has

```
resources :users, :only => :show
```

The user view has

```
User: #{link_to user.name, user}
```

The view spec has

```
describe 'home/index.html.haml' do
  it 'should render the users' do
    @users = User.all
    render
  end
end
```

It does the right thing if I hit the app locally but if I run rspec on the view, I get

```
Failure/Error: render
  ActionView::Template::Error:
    undefined method `user_path' for #<#<Class:0x109f2a468>:0x109db5128>
```

Comment: What is the actual line from the rspec file?

Comment: Updated question with rspec content.

Answer (score 1):

`Spork` turned out to be the culprit. Restarted it and the specs now pass.